# Yii2 - Using javascript to update a dynamic from element with wbraganca dynamicform

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, dynamicform

I have a dynamic form for Product Orders. I am setting the price based on company(select2) and product using `onchange` from the product `dropDownList`. Company is on the base form outside the `dynamicform` (easy to reference) but product is a list item within the `dynamicform`. My code is working for the first item but I cannot set the subsequent because I cannot figure out how to address the item # of the added dynamic form items.

dynamic form loop:

```
 <?php foreach ($modelsOrderItem as $o => $modelOrderItem): ?>
    <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php
                // necessary for update action.
                if (! $modelOrderItem->isNewRecord) {
                    echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelOrderItem, "[{$o}]id");
                }
            ?>

            <div class="pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">

                <?= $form->field($modelOrderItem, "[{$o}]idProduct")->
                    dropDownList
                    (
                        ArrayHelper::map(Product::find()->all(), 'id','ProductCodeWithName'),
                        ['prompt' => 'Select a Product','style'=>'width:400px' ,

                        'onchange' => '$.post( "index.php?r=pricelist/pricelist&idProduct='.'"+$(this).val()+"'.'&idCompany='.'"+$("#order-idcompany").val(),
                            function(data)
                            {
                                    $( "#orderitem-0-itemprice" ).val(data);
                            });']

                    )->label(false);

                ?>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3" >
                    <?= $form->field($modelOrderItem, "[{$o}]itemQuantity")->textInput(['style'=>'width:150px'])->label(false) ?> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                    <?= $form->field($modelOrderItem, "[{$o}]itemPrice")->textInput(['style'=>'width:200px'])->label(false) ?>
            </div>

        </div><!-- .row -->
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have now removed the onchange function and added Javascript that allows me to control which form element to change but, I cannot figure out how to do this with dynamically added elements. I have included script looking for a change in the added price element but the script does not get activated. So it works for the zero(0) element but will not respond with orderitem1, etc. Here is my updated code and the Javascript.

```
                <div class="container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->
            <?php foreach ($modelsOrderItem as $o => $modelOrderItem):?>
                <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <?php
                            // necessary for update action.
                            if (! $modelOrderItem->isNewRecord)
                            {
                                echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelOrderItem, "[{$o}]id");
                            }
                        ?>
                        <div class="form-group kv-fieldset-inline">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">

                                <?= $form->field($modelOrderItem, "[{$o}]idProduct")->dropDownList
                                    (
                                        ArrayHelper::map(Product::find()->orderBy('productCode')->all(), 'id','ProductCodeWithName'),
                                        ['prompt' => 'Select a Product','style'=>'width:360px' ,]

                                    )->label(false);
                                ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-2" >
                                    <?= $form->field($modelOrderItem, "[{$o}]itemQuantity")->textInput(['style'=>'width:100px','padding'=>'100px'])->label(false) ?> 
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-2" >
                                    <?= $form->field($modelOrderItem, "[{$o}]quantityType")->DropdownList(['Cartons'=>'Cartons','Bags'=>'Bags','Kilograms'=>'Kilograms',
                                            'Tubs'=>'Tubs', 'Pieces' => 'Pieces'],['style'=>'width:150px'])->label(false) ?> 
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelOrderItem, "[{$o}]itemPrice")->textInput(['style'=>'width:200px'])->label(false) ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                                <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- .row -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 <?php
    $script = "$('#orderitem-0-idproduct').change(function()
        {
            var idProduct = $(this).val();
            $.get( 'index.php?r=pricelist/getpricelist&idProduct',{ idProduct:idProduct, idCompany:$model->idCompany },
            function(data)
            {
                    $('#orderitem-0-itemprice').val(data);
            });
        });
        $('#orderitem-1-idproduct').change(function()
        {
            var idProduct1 = $(this).val(data);
            alert();
            $.get( 'index.php?r=pricelist/getpricelist&idProduct',{ idProduct:idProduct1, idCompany:$model->idCompany },
            function(data)
            {
                    $('#orderitem-1-itemprice').val(data);
            });
        });";
    $this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Comment: I forgot to add that I understand I am referencing the "0" element but I cannot figure out how to substitute the row/item # here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use Javascript to find out which element was being clicked. This avoided the problem of being able to run code on dynamic elements that had not been initiated.

```
    <?php $js = <<<JS

    $('body').change(function(e)
    {
        var element = '#'+$(e.target).attr('id');
        var field = element.substring(element.length - number_of_chars_in_your_fieldname, element.length);  //stripping the string to identify the field you are looking 

        if(field === "field_you_are_looking_for")  //element usually looks like #formID-row-field
        {
            var dropdownID = $(element).val();
            if (element.length === 22)              //single digit row numbers
            {
                var row = element.substring(11,12);  //extract the current row number
            } else                                   //row numbers higher than 9
            {
                var row = element.substring(11,13); 
            }
            //Do whatever you need to do

            $('#formID-'+row+'-field_you_want_to_change').val(data);  //set the field to change on current row
        }
    });
JS;

    $this->registerJs($js);

?>
```